# MYSQL Optimize Statement

Tags: mysql, xampp, mariadb

I am trying to use the optimize statement on the Shell of the MYSQL system and have tried using

```
mysqlcheck -o --all-databases;
mysqlcheck -o <databasename>;
```

However, it does not work and showed me an error,

[image: Error Here]

Is there any other command that could make it work? I am running the script on xampp shell for mysql and would like to just check the optimization for the table. I know that there would errors for it however I would like to view it.

Comment: It's a shell command, not something you type at the `mysql>` prompt.

Comment: oh i see! is there a command on the mysql prompt to optimize the tables?

Comment: `OPTIMIZE TABLE tablename`

Comment: But I don't think there's a SQL command to do an entire database or all databases. You need to use the shell command for that.

Answer (score 0):

`mysqlcheck` is a command to give to the OS via its "shell".  It is *not* a command to use inside the "commandline tool" `mysql`; that would be `OPTIMIZE TABLE` as mentioned in a Comment.

But...  Why do you think you want to Optimize all the tables.  While the name "optimize" is tempting, it is rarely worth bothering with.